Macbook Pro 2019 with BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter, with Debian 12 (Weekly): But, NO WiFi
After struggling a lot, I could finally install Debian 12 (Weekly) using ISO CD & Ethernet cable on MacbookPro 2019 with Intel & T2:
I did the following:
$ sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
enx00e04c680318  no wireless extensions.

$ lspci -nn | grep Network
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM4364 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4464] (rev 04)

/etc/modprobe.d$ ls -l
total 12
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 180 Dec 26  2022 broadcom-sta-dkms.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 127 Mar  7 10:33 dkms.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 154 Mar 12 23:28 intel-microcode-blacklist.conf

$ sudo apt-get install linux-image-$(uname -r)
linux-image-6.6.15-amd64 is already the newest version (6.6.15-2).

$ sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)

$ sudo apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms

$ find /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/updates
/lib/modules/6.6.15-amd64/updates
/lib/modules/6.6.15-amd64/updates/dkms
/lib/modules/6.6.15-amd64/updates/dkms/wl.ko.xz

$ sudo modprobe -r b44 b43 b43legacy ssb brcmsmac bcma

$ sudo modprobe wl

$ cat /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

$ nmcli networking on

Added the PATH to modprobe in .bashrc file:

export PATH=$PATH:/sbin:/usr/sbin

Still the WiFi is NOT showing up.
Any Help?

Please [edit] the question and add relevant info like the proper identification of the WiFi device. Use lspcito get it then copy the relevant line. That it is a dual-boot is totally irrelevant.

No additional installation required, it's supported in Debian since a long time ago. However, knowing that those are unsigned modules you may have to deal with Secure Boot and use MOKutil: https://wiki.debian.org/SecureBoot

`$ sudo mokutil --sb-state
SecureBoot disabled`
Can you kindly tell me the steps that I should do?

If so, bad news, this news: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/752257/macbook-pros-wifi-doesnt-work-on-a-fresh-pop-os-install

I’m voting to close this question because question has been answered on Unix SE site. Link in comments.

@ChanganAuto
THANK YOU VERY MUCH!!! I got the ground reality from your guidance. Then, with the help of some more guidance from my posting in Reddit, and with some work around, some how the WiFi started to work now. Now, I have another problem: there is NO sound for videos... Once again, with immense thanks and gratitude
